# wanted to install the windows xp

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, windows-xp

I have installed the unbutu latest version on my laptop. then i am trying to install the windows xp as dual boot . could any body please suggest me how to do it . i have tried the following procedure ,but it is not working

1) Inserted the Xp CD then loading the the cd . but it is not working

please can any body give a solution for my problem

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to boot a live ubuntu disk and resize ubuntu to make room for xp using gparted
You should know xp only supports 3 primary partitions on a hdd (the partition table supports 4, guess xp can't count)
next use the boot menu to select your disk driver for booting using the boot menu, there should be info as soon as you hit the power button at the bottom of the screen, if you cant find it read the manual for the laptop
after installing xp you will need to boot a live disk and reinstall grub:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
Windows XP does not support secure boot and will not boot with it enabled
You should look into use [virtualbox](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox) for running xp, assuming your cpu supports VT, you may need to enable this in your bios
You will need to use the left ctrl key when accepting the eula for windows xp in virtualbox